# Change the color of the active link and keep a different color for the other ones

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a list of unordered links. what i want is to have the active link that is clicked to change the color to e.g red.
all the other links should be e.g brown.

when another link is clicked the previous one that was clicked before should be brown and the active one red.
i have managed to do something with Jquery but the problem is that even though i get what i want, the links when clicked do not navigate to the page requested.

the sample code follows below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.list li a').click(function() {
                     $('.list li a').css('color', '#888');
                     $(this).css('color', '#678DBC');
                     return false;   
                     
                     $(this).css('color', '#678DBC');
                });
        });
```

```html
<ul class="list">
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have tried the solutions and even though it worked on jsfiddle, my page (an asp.net mvc page) it did not work....

i have the output of the html code (from my asp.net mvc page) + the css rule + the jquery code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jLo2uesa/

my page is http://geroshop.devtool.gr/%CE%B8%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%83%CE%B7-%CF%88%CF%8D%CE%BE%CE%B7-%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%86%CE%AE%CF%82

the links are on the left (are in greek but it is not a problem). when clicked i want e.g to change to red and all the rest to be grey. then if another is clicked all to be grey but the one that clicked.it does not work....

please do a page source view on the page above to see that the jquery and html are correct...i have added a css rule .active{color:red;} to the styles.css file of the site

thanks

Comment: You need to assign the "active" link a class or id that identifies it as such. Then assign the color change to the active class/id in your CSS and you're good to go.

Comment: Remove `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the

```
return false;
```

It prevents bubbling and the default event of the anchor. I am not sure why you need it there.

```
$('.list li a').click(function() {
    $('.list li a').css('color', '#888');
    $(this).css('color', '#678DBC');
    $(this).css('color', '#678DBC');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="myList" class="list">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Google</a></li> 
    <li><a target="_blank" href="www.microsoft.de">Microsoft</a></li>    
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myList").find("a").click(function(e){
        $("#myList").find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(e.target).addClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

You just need to declare a css-class with your desired style for the link called "active".

Comment: it does work on fiddle but not in my page. this is an asp.net mvc page. the page source of the asp.net mvc page (html)

Comment: @user2836790 do not edit the answer, edit your question if you have updates, fro your invalid edit, the link's href value is all encoded

Comment: @user2836790: Without any more details I cannot help you. As you can see this snippet itself works. So I'd bet that some details on how you actually used/implemented/copied it would proof useful. Also console logs if available may help.